# How to manage cookies that are populated behind the scenes

Tags: jmeter

I am supposed to load check our web - application. When a request comes for the first time the app would verify the browser and set a browserid to the cookies. Am not being able to set this value due to which am getting session timed out message. Is there a way to handle this? the cookie is set in the action class so i guess scraping is not a solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you added a 'HTTP Cookie Manager' to your test tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a [HTTP Cookie Manage](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)r at the Test Plan Level